# Linq Join table AND nullable variable

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a LINQ Query on Ef6 using a join on the db.ClincalAssets table where the AssetDisposalID Field is null

i.e. I don't want rows of data from that table where the AssetDisposalID is not null

The following code doesn't appear to work because it returns the same 23 results I had before I modified the code

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var tomorrow = today.AddDays(30);


            var dateresult = db.ClinicalINSs.GroupBy(d => d.ClinicalAssetID)
                       .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.NextInspectionDate)
                                         .Take(1));


            var ClinicalIDVM = (from s in dateresult.Where(q => q.NextInspectionDate <= tomorrow)
                                join co in db.ClinicalAssets.Where (t => t.AssetDisposalID == null) on  s.ClinicalAssetID  equals co.ClinicalAssetID into AR
                                let subred = AR.OrderByDescending(subredASS => subredASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()
                                join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                                let subpat = AP.OrderByDescending(SubPATASS => SubPATASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()
                                orderby s.NextInspectionDate descending


                                select new ClinicalIDVM
                                {
                                    ClinicalAssetID = s.ClinicalAssetID,
                                    ProductName = subred.ProductName ,
                                    SerialNo = subred.SerialNo == null ? "" : subred.SerialNo,
                                    InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate,
                                   NextInspectionDate = s.NextInspectionDate == null ? (DateTime?)null : s.NextInspectionDate,

                               }).ToList();
```

i have also tried this:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
           var tomorrow = today.AddDays(30);


           var dateresult = db.ClinicalINSs.GroupBy(d => d.ClinicalAssetID)
                      .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.NextInspectionDate)
                                        .Take(1));


           var ClinicalIDVM = (from s in dateresult from Disp in db.ClinicalAssets where s.NextInspectionDate <= tomorrow && Disp.AssetDisposalID == null

                               join co in db.ClinicalAssets on  s.ClinicalAssetID  equals co.ClinicalAssetID into AR
                               let subred = AR.OrderByDescending(subredASS => subredASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()

                               join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID into AP
                               let subpat = AP.OrderByDescending(SubPATASS => SubPATASS.ClinicalAssetID).FirstOrDefault()

                               orderby s.NextInspectionDate descending


                               select new ClinicalIDVM
                               {
                                   ClinicalAssetID = s.ClinicalAssetID,
                                   ProductName = subred.ProductName ,
                                   SerialNo = subred.SerialNo == null ? "" : subred.SerialNo,
                                   InspectionDate = subpat.InspectionDate,
                                  NextInspectionDate = s.NextInspectionDate == null ? (DateTime?)null : s.NextInspectionDate,

                              }).ToList();
```

but I get al records duplicated.

Comment: "returns the same 23 results as before" -- before what?

Comment: before the change to filter the result

Comment: I'd suggest you first add navigation properties to your model, so you don't need to `join` any more, which usually makes it much easier to compose queries. And which -- when properly named -- also makes it much easier to understand your question.